# What does "if you have anything else to say" mean?

Tags: meaning, politeness

> if you have anything else to say

What does it mean? Is it offensive or respectful to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is very much self-explanatory. "If you have anything else to say" means the addresser is asking for a clarification whether the addressee has something else to say or add to their previous statements.

Using the sentence "If you have anything else to say, please add..." in a formal conversation could be offensive. If you are an interviewer, you should probably think of using sentences like:

- Do you have anything else to say about yourself?
- Is there anything else we should know about you?

Again if you are using this sentence in an informal conversation with an archenemy, it would probably piss them off. Hence it would be recommended to use a kinder and more polite tone when addressing this issue.

Also if you are thinking of adding this line in the plot of a story, then again you can use it at your own convenience.